# Repeating patterns in a vector in R

Tags: r, pattern-matching

If a vector is produced from a vector of unknown length with unique elements by repeating it unknown times

`small_v <- c("as","d2","GI","Worm")`

`big_v <- rep(small_v, 3)`

then how to determine how long that vector was and how many times it was repeated?

So in this example the original length was 4 and it repeats 3 times.

Realistically in my case the vectors will be fairly small and will be repeated only a few times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** If the elements are all repeating and no other values are there, then use

```
length(big_v)/length(unique(big_v))
[1] 3
```

---

**2)** Or use

```
library(data.table)
max(rowid(big_v))
[1] 3
```

Comment: The issue is that I don't have small_v. Big_v only.

Comment: Ok now I feel dumb.. Was so easy actually.

Answer (score 2):

**1)** Assuming that there is at least one unique element in `small_v` (which is the case in the question since it assumes all elements in `small_v` are unique):

```
min(table(big_v))
## [1] 3
```

or using pipes

```
big_v |> table() |> min()
## [1] 3
```

Here is a more difficult test but it still works because `small_v2[2]` is unique in `small_v2` even though the other elements of `small_v2` are not unique.

```
# test data
small_v2 <- c(small_v, small_v[-2])
big_v2 <- rep(small_v2, 3)

min(table(big_v2))
## [1] 3
```

**2)** If we knew that the first element of `small_v` were unique (which is the case in the question since it assumes all elements in `small_v` are unique) then this would work:

```
sum(big_v[1] == big_v)
## [1] 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively we could use `rle` with `with` to count the repeats

```r
with(rle(sort(big_v)), max(lengths))
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-04 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

```r
[1] 3
```